# JavaFX Slider ticks not showing correctly

Tags: java, javafx, slider

What I want to do:
Have a slider, from 0 - 10, have it move only by a full tick(1), and show the value of the tick above the tick.

What happens: 
It shows all values from 0-10 except for 9 which is mysteriously missing..

I wanted to upload an image here but I lack the reputation it seems ;)

https://pasteboard.co/HdPtzVp.png

Code:
Main Class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StartGui extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        HBox box = new HBox();
        PionnenSlider slider = new PionnenSlider();
        box.getChildren().add(slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("SliderMinimalCode");
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Slider class:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

public class PionnenSlider extends Slider
{

    public PionnenSlider()
    {
        setMinorTickCount(0);
        setBlockIncrement(1);
        setMajorTickUnit(1);  

        setValue(0);
        setMax(10);
        setShowTickMarks(true);
        setShowTickLabels(true);
        setSnapToTicks(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: something wrong in the code your are not showing ;) please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: ... and don't extend a control (nor any other class) if you can reach the same by configuration

Comment: The only changes to slider happen inside the class PionnenSlider

Comment: Hmm .. your example does show the second last tick label (the 9) as expected. Only if I decrease the width of the window to minimum, it's not shown due to missing space. And again: dont extend - there's no need for PionnenSlider, it's simply configured with public api!

Comment: Doesn't this happen because there is not enough space for 9 to be shown? Increasing dimensions would solve the problem. Example [here](https://gfycat.com/SolidMindlessCanine).

Comment: Copy pasted the code I uploaded here and replaced what I had in my project with it, ran it again and it shows as it does in the picture I linked, every number present except for 9, when trying to drag the windows size smaller than the slider it doesn't allow this and stops decreasing the horizontal size after the label for 10, I'm kind of confused how you can run the same code and get the expected result, but when I do it it doesn't show 9 >.<  p.s. If it was due to lack of space, shouldn't 10 disappear first? 8 is present, 10 is present, 9 is not

Comment: I increased the minimum size of the slider & now it does show all labels for ticks. is there any way to do this so it automaticly decides how much space it needs?

Comment: The reason the 9 disappears before the 10 is because it tries to show the first and last value rather than in-between values

Answer (score 0):

apparently it is due to lack of space for the slider, found a workaround to automaticly size it with HBox.setHgrow(sliderPionnen, Priority.ALWAYS);, although that just grows it to fill the entire HBOX.. so I guess I'l have to find a workaround for that